# How to define a template overide's function in a non-inline way

Tags: c++, class, templates, overriding, overloading

Hi so I have a template class called Body, that takes a single sf::Drawable descendant as a template argument, and i'm trying to overide the Render() function only for the case that the template argument is a sf::Shape.

**How do i do this in a non-inline way?** The code works when I define the function inside the class, automatically making it inline, but I get **link errors (multiple Render symbols detected)** when I define the function in a seperate .cpp file.

If it helps here's the code that produces an error:

```
// in the header file
template<typename drawable= void>
class Body : public sf::Drawable
{
    void Render(){Do_Something();
}

template <> 
class Body<Shape> : public sf::Drawable
{
    void Render();
}

// in the cpp file
void Body<Shape>::Render()
{
    Do_Something_Else();
}
```

Comment: What link errors? You need to a closing brace in the definition of the first `Render()`, you need to terminate your class definitions with a `;` and your definition of `Body<Shape>::Render()` should be `template<> void Body<Shape>::Render() { Do_Something_Else(); }` but those would normally be a compile errors, not a link error.

Comment: There are no linker errors because the code does not compile. After I fix typos and define pieces you have omitted, I don't get any linker errors either. Please post a complete compilable example together with the commands you use to compile and link, and any error messages you are getting, verbatim.

Comment: Apparently it is not an original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
template <typename T> 
struct Foo {
    int frob() const;
};

// Note: Member function specializations do not require 
//       full class specializations.

template <typename T> 
int Foo<T>::frob() const { return 42; }

template <> 
int Foo<float>::frob() const { return 0xbeef; }


#include <iostream>
int main () {
    std::cout << Foo<int>().frob() << '\n';
    std::cout << Foo<float>().frob() << '\n';
}
```

Note that the specializations need to be visible where you use them, so in most cases, you have to put them in the header, too.

Comment: yes, I didn't put the template indication before the definition, Thanks!

Comment: However, next time please post real code, yours was not even syntactically valid. Maybe also update the code in your question. Could have justified a removal of my own question "You mean like this?" ;)

Comment: Oh, and note that my code is different from yours. You define a whole new class template specialization, whereas mine does just specialize a single member function, and keeps the class template untouched.

Comment: You still need to put the declaration of the specialization into the header, otherwise the compiler will just generate a definition from the prime template, as it can not know that somewhere in some other TU there is a specialization lurking.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Of course it is only used where visible. I'll edit my answer to emphasize this.